# CMake command not working in VS Code task

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-code

I have created a task in my `tasks.json` file in Visual Studio Code:

```
{
    "label": "cmake",
    "command": "cmake",
    "args": [
        "-G",
        "\"Unix Makefiles\"",
        "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug",
        ".."
    ],
    "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/build"
    },
    "problemMatcher": []
},
```

When I run it from within VSC (Tasks: run task > cmake), I get the following error:

```
> Executing task: cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .. <

CMake Error: Could not create named generator "Unix Makefiles"

Generators
  Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
  Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.
  Xcode                        = Generate Xcode project files.
  CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeLite - Ninja             = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Unix Makefiles    = Generates CodeLite project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Ninja       = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Kate - Ninja                 = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Unix Makefiles        = Generates Kate project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja         = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.

The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

However if I execute the exact same command in terminal it works as expected:

```
oyvinds-MacBook:build oyvindhauge$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/oyvindhauge/Documents/Development/[PROJECT]/build
oyvinds-MacBook:build oyvindhauge$
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I am not expert in VS Code, but error message smells like a **quoted string** has been passed as generator: `"Unix Makefiles"`. Probably, there is no needs in adding additional quotation around `-G` parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like stated in the comments, removing the extra quotes around generator param `"Unix Makefiles"` fixed the problem.